# UISplitViewController inside UITabBarController giving errors when it tries to check for [splitViewController viewControllers]

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)[[tabBarController viewControllers] firstObject];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[splitViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
}
```

This is my current code to check if the device is an iPad. If it is, it should set the tabbarcontroller's first object's last object's only view controller. The storyboard goes as following:

```
Tabbarcontroller[0]>Splitviewcontroller[1]>Navigationcontroller[0]>delegate(?)
```

I still have no idea what the delegate does, but upon checking apple's template code for a split view controller, I think it uses the delegate to notify the detail view controller to update content. The line I'm crashing is `[splitViewController viewControllers]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple Guides `UISplitViewController` should be the root view controller i. e. it cannot be inserted into `UITabBarController` as child controller:

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from a
>   UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window.

From "View Controller Catalog for iOS" User Guide

Comment: I guess that's correct, but why is it throwing an error at [splitViewController viewControllers]?

Comment: @Schemetrical Place a breakpoint on this line and `po [[tabBarController viewControllers] firstObject]`. I don't think it will be an instance of UISplitViewController type because in this case the behaviour is undefined